# Magento 2: How to get the themes detail that are used by my magento site?

Tags: magento2, theme

I was trying to get the theme detail used by the Magento but got nothing till now.
I am using this method still get nothing special.

```
  public static function ThemeDetail(){
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
             $connection= $objectManager->getConnection();
             $theme_table = $objectManager->getTableName('theme');   
             $theme_data = $connection->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM ".$theme_table);
             if(!empty($theme_data)){
                foreach($theme_data as $theme_name => $value){
                 $themeArray[] = array('name'=> $theme_data[$theme_name]['theme_title'], 'version'=>'2.0.5');    
                }

              return $themeArray; 
             } else {
              return FALSE; 
             }

      }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your class will need to have dependency on the following:

```
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
\Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\ThemeProviderInterface
```

Use this method to get data for current theme:

```
public function getThemeData()
    {
        $themeId = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            \Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface::XML_PATH_THEME_ID,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        );

        /** @var $theme \Magento\Framework\View\Design\ThemeInterface */
        $theme = $this->_themeProvider->getThemeById($themeId);

        return $theme->getData();
    }
```

Comment: For me the `getThemeById` is always returns null. In the factory the function has only 1 row, `return null`. I've tried to delete the generated (I am in developer mode) but no success. I've checked, `$themeId` is 5 and that is in the `theme` table and that is our current theme.

Comment: Ok, I've figured out. You need to use `Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\ThemeProvider` instead `\Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\ThemeProvider`

Answer (score 3):

you have to just keep below content for your function,

```
Use directly objectmanager is not right way, use __construct() way to define your class inside block is better way to use coding standard.
```

code for below,

```
  public static function ThemeDetail(){
        $connection = $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection')->getConnection('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION');

    $version = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface');


             $theme_table = $connection->getTableName('theme');   
             $theme_data = $connection->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM ".$theme_table);

             $themeArray = array();
             if(!empty($theme_data)){
                foreach($theme_data as $value){ echo $value['theme_title'];
                 $themeArray[] = array('name'=> $value['theme_title'], 'version'=>$version->getVersion());    
                }
             } else {
                return FALSE; 
             }

           echo "<pre>";print_r($themeArray);exit;

      }
```

Comment: as you see here i don't want to give the version hard-coded actually.

Comment: you have defined 2.0.5 in your code

Comment: yes,  this was defined by me but is there any way to get the theme version by programming not hard coded.Themes names get from the database but there is no version specified.

Comment: i have updated my answer

Comment: what is $version->getVersion()  ? is this directly get the version of theme

Comment: yes its display version of your magento, not the theme version

Comment: Is there any way to get the theme version also.

Comment: i dont know for theme version, i havent seen theme version in magento 2

Comment: lol. as you mentioned, using object manager is a very bad practice, but using raw sql is the same.

Answer (score 2):

**Use for Theme object**

> `$this->_design->getDesignTheme()`

**and theme id:**

> `$this->_design->getDesignTheme()->getId()`

where *`$this->_design`*  instance of `Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface`